# How to get focus on a subform in LibreOffice Base using tab

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-base

The question and answer [LibreOffice Base; Tab order from mainform to subform](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27290279/1036599) almost solve the issue I have, but not completely.

I have a table `mytable` (`id, name, textfield`). I'm displaying `id` and `name` in a form with a table layout (table control). I've added the column `textfield` from the same table as a subform with a text box control (the reason is that I want to enter text with newlines, while being able to navigate the records quickly in the main table). Here's what it looks like in design view:

[image: Form and subform from one table]

I've added this Basic macro, based on the two answers linked above:

```
Sub Main

Dim root_doc As Object
Dim form_container, form_ctrlr As Object
Dim main_frm, sub_frm, tab_target As Object
root_doc = ThisComponent
form_container = root_doc.Drawpage.Forms
form_ctrlr = root_doc.getCurrentController()
main_frm = form_container.getByName("MainForm")
sub_frm = main_frm.getByName("SubForm")
tab_target = sub_frm.getByName("TextField")
form_ctrlr.getControl(tab_target).setFocus()

End Sub
```

Now, if I add the macro on the event `When losing focus` of the `name` column, I do get focus on the textbox when pressing Tab, but on the next row.

If I add the macro to the event `On key press` of the `name` column, I get what I want when pressing e.g. `Space`, but `Tab` or `Enter` only take me to the next row in the main form.

**Is there a way to get this to work with `Tab`?**

Comment: Also posted at https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/190449/how-to-get-focus-on-a-subform-in-libreoffice-base-using-tab/ where an answer is given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Options to solve this, from the answers over at [ask.libreoffice.org](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/190449/how-to-get-focus-on-a-subform-in-libreoffice-base-using-tab/):

1. Just use the standard `Ctrl + Tab` to switch focus.
2. Assign a macro to a custom key combination and use that. Not all combinations work, I settled on `Shft + Enter`.

And the macro (provided by user Ratslinger):

```
Sub Main
    Dim oForm, oCtrlr, oField As Object
    oForm = ThisComponent.Drawpage.Forms.getByName("MainForm")
    oCtrlr = ThisComponent.getCurrentController()
    oField = main_frm.getByName("TextField")
    oCtrlr.getControl(oField).setFocus()
End Sub
```